# Dynamic Placeholder in Vue 3 with Global Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to set dynamic text for the `placeholder` attribute on my search bar. Depending on the page, I want the text in the search bar to be different (I will define it in `data())`.

However, since the search bar component is a global component, it doesn't seem to be editable.

*(As you see below is my try, I did it with `v-model` based on `Vue` docs, however when I try with placeholder it doesn't work...)*

*Snippet 1* - Search bar component

```
<template>
    <!-- Search Componenet -->
    <div class="mx-5 mb-3 form-group">
        <br>
        <input class="mb-5 form-control" type="search" :placeholder="placeholderValue" :value="modelValue" @load="$emit('update:placeholderValue', $event.target.value)" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['modelValue', 'placeholderValue'],
    emits: ['update:modelValue', 'update:placeholderValue']
}
</script>
```

*Snippet 2* - Album.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="AlbumView">
    
        <h1>{{header}}</h1>
        <h2>{{header2}}</h2>
        <br>
    
        <!-- Search Componenet -->
    
        <SearchComponent :placeholder="placeholderValue" v-model="searchQuery" />
    
        <!-- Dynamic Song Route Button -->
        <div class="button-container-all mx-5 pb-5">
    
            <div v-for="item in datanew" :key="item.id">
                {{ item.album }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { datatwo } from '@/data2'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            placeholderValue: "Search for Albums here...",
            datanew: datatwo,
            searchQuery: null,
            header: "Browse by Album",
            header2: "Select an Album:",
            publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL

        };
    },
}
</script>
```

If this is possible?

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is that you have a typo in the binding name. In the search bar component, the prop is named `placeholderValue`, but your binding is `:placeholder="..."` when it should be `:placeholderValue="..."`.

Comment: Tx. But how can I then assign that value as the placeholder.

Comment: You're already doing that correctly in the search bar component.

Comment: The only fix needed here: Change `<SearchComponent :placeholder="placeholderValue" v-model="searchQuery" />` to `<SearchComponent :placeholderValue="placeholderValue" v-model="searchQuery" />`

Comment: And you can remove the `update:placeholderValue` code in the search bar component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it with v-model (the Childcomponent changes the value of the placeholder) you have to use `v-model:placeholder` for it to work.
And also `placeholderValue` is not the way to go the "Value" at the end of a prop is only needed for modelValue which is the default v-model-binding (v-model="") but if you want named v-model-binding (v-model:placeholder="") you do not want to add the "Value" in the props and emits arrays.

Example:

usage of SearchComponent

```js
<SearchComponent :placeholder="'placeholderValue'" v-model="searchQuery" />
```

instead of `'placeholderValue'` you can put any string you want or variable. I just put the string 'placeholderValue' as an example.

SearchComponent

```js
<template>
    <!-- Search Componenet -->
    <div class="mx-5 mb-3 form-group">
        <br>
        <input class="mb-5 form-control" type="search" :placeholder="placeholder" :value="modelValue" @load="$emit('update:placeholderValue', $event.target.value)" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "SearchComponent",
    props: ['modelValue', 'placeholder'],
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```